# Android:execute web page in a service

Tags: android

I want to open a web page in a service in android activity then after the web executed I want to get the new URL.

I want to use a website for e.g  ” www.example.com/login.jsp?username=xxx&password=YYY “
to check the validity of the username and password, if the user exist I will have in the new 
URL www.example.com/fstPage.jsp

help PlZ

thanks

Comment: As long as you don't open up the connection the UI thread, this should be relatively simple.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should to check validity at the second link. Server side should include method that accept request like www.example.com/fstPage.jsp?username=XXX&password=YYY, and then server get back appropriate site.

I think that is pretty good way to do this at easiest way. Why to use redirection...

```
public class Example extends Activity {
    WebView webview;
    String url;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading", true);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewBuy);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        url = "www.example.com/fstPage.jsp" + "?username="
                + User.getUsername() + "&password=" + User.getPassword();
        webview.loadUrl(url);

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view,
                    SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                handler.proceed();
            }
            @Override
              public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
              pd.dismiss();
            }
        }); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you

How can I get the new URL after executing the authentication page?

I am a beginner in android programing…

and can this work in a service?

Thanks

Comment: You won't get new URL,just make a method on a server side that accepts something like  returnFstPage which gets parameters username and password, check if user exist and then return page.

But if want it in that way: first make :
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("www.example.com/fstPage.jsp" + "?username="+ username + "&password=" + password);
HttpResponse response =client.execute(post);

Check what server returns and if that is ok, then just do action in my post.

Comment: how can i check what server return?